# Geolocation inside angular js factory not working when redirected to a page

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, google-geolocation

I am using factory method to get user's current location. Below is my factory method:

```
app.factory('FactoryName', function($http, $q, $window){ 
    'use strict';
    function getCurrentPosition() {
        var deferred = $q.defer();

        if (!$window.navigator.geolocation) {
            deferred.reject('Geolocation not supported.');
        } else {
            $window.navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(
                function (position) {
                    deferred.resolve(position);
                },
                function (err) {
                    deferred.reject(err);
                });
        }

        return deferred.promise;
    }    

    return {
        getCurrentPosition: getCurrentPosition
    };      
});
```

Now inside controller I am getting user's current location as follows:

```
FactoryName.getCurrentPosition().then(UserLocationFound).catch(UserLocationNotFound);
var UserLocationFound = function(data, status) {
   $scope.latitude = data.coords.latitude;
   $scope.longitude = data.coords.longitude;
};
var UserLocationNotFound = function(data, error) { 
   console.log("location not found")
};
```

Lets say the url of this page is "domain.com/form" and when I directly go to this page then its working fine, "then" and "catch" are fired accordingly to the situation. But the problem arises when I go to this page from some other page(anchor tag linkage). In this case none of the events are fired. I am unable to understand why it is working in one case and not in the other.